# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE skipping rows without warnings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
primaryid INT PRIMARY KEY,
caseid INT,
pt varchar(80)
);
```

Here is what my data looks like:

```
primaryid$caseid$pt
100640841$10064084$Pulmonary embolism
32990183$3299018$Pyrexia
32990183$3299018$Rash maculo-papular
32990183$3299018$Swelling face
35387833$3538783$Obesity
375988510$3759885$Gastric polyps
375988510$3759885$Gastritis atrophic
```

I Have loaded it into MySQL using the following statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/input.txt' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (primaryid, caseid,pt) ;
```

and I get as a result:

```
Query OK, 171925 rows affected (2.75 sec)
Records: 545256  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 373331  Warnings: 0
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? 
Why are 373331 records skipped and there are no warnings?

Is this an syntax issue or a problem with the data file, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your `primaryid` column as a `PRIMARY KEY` which means that it must be *unique*.  In your sample records alone, there's three lines with `32990183` as `primaryid`.  Only one of those records will the loaded, the rest will be skipped.

You either need to fix your data, or not make `primaryid` a primary key.